# Reload page with Django Listview class after receiving data from Ajax GET Method

Tags: ajax, django, get, django-views

I'm using a js calendar picker plugin to pass the date value to django view, and base on the date it should render new view to the same web page. Since in this view I'm pulling tons of data from different tables, I use ListView class.

Question is, when I use the get function in listview, I'm able to capture the data passed from ajax. How do I pass that data to get_context_data to regenerate the context and reload the page?

Thx

Here is my js:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            var start = moment().subtract(29, 'days');
            var end = moment();

            function cb(start, end) {
                $('#reportrange span').html(start.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('MMMM D, YYYY'));    
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: "/csr/summary/",
                    data: {
                        csrfmiddlewaretoken: $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val(),
                        from_date: from_date,
                        to_date: to_date,
                    },
                    success: function (response) {
                    }
                });

                console.log("done here");
            }

            $('#reportrange').daterangepicker({
                startDate: start,
                endDate: end,
                ranges: {
                    'Today': [moment(), moment()],
                    'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
                    'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
                }
            }, cb);
            cb(start, end);
        });
    </script>
```

And here is my view:

```
class CsrView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'dash/csr.html'
    context_object_name = 'csr_list'
    from_date = ""
    to_date = ""

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.from_date = self.request.GET.get("from_date", "")
        self.to_date = self.request.GET.get("to_date", "")
        print "Django get method getting:", self.from_date, " - ", self.to_date
        return super(CsrView, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(CsrView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

        # if self.request.method == "GET":
        #     print "get method triggered"
        #     self.from_date = self.request.GET.get("from_date", "")
        #     self.to_date = self.request.GET.get("to_date", "")
        #     context['testing'] = "lalala" + self.from_date

        context['title'] = "CSR"
        context['other_stuff'] = .....
```

Comment: What are you doing with CSRF in a GET request?

Answer (score 0):

When you call super from get mthod get_context_data method should be called according to super method of super class.

Check below url you will see in last of get method `context = self.get_context_data()`

https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.11/django.views.generic.list/ListView/#get

Comment: Got it, now I'm able to get the data in get_context_data as well, but how do I reload the page with the new data ? Thx

Comment: why you want to reload page? I think you should append data using js if you are showing data like pagination

Comment: I'm not using pagination for this. This suppose to be a simple get method. But since I'm using this calendar plugin in js, I have to use js to create a get request, and this request have to pass the data to django view and reload the page. I'm very new to js and ajax, so I wonder what's the best way to do this.